# How to fix 'json atom at path "name" is missing'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, api, serialization

I'm doing a serializer for my application and i need to test it, but it always return 'json atom at path "name" is missing' when i run the specs. I'm using FastJson do build my serializer.

My StudentSerializer (all the attributes is in Students Model):

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class Api::V2::StudentSerializer < ApplicationSerializer
  attributes :email, :name, :school_id
end
```

My StudentSerializer_Spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Api::V2::StudentSerializer, type: :serializer do

  subject(:serializer) { described_class.new(student) }

  context 'is student serialize working?' do
    let(:student) { build_stubbed(:student) }

    it 'serializes' do
      Api::V2:: StudentSerializer.new (student)
      expect(serializer).to include_json(
        name: student.name
      )
    end
  end
end
```

When i run the rspec, that's the result i get:

```
Api::V2::StudentSerializer
  is student serialize working?
    serializes (FAILED - 1)

  1) Api::V2::StudentSerializer is student serialize working? serializes
     Failure/Error:
       expect(serializer).to include_json(
         name: student.name
       )

                 json atom at path "name" is missing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out!

By using FastJson, the Json start with 'data:':

```
{:data=>
  {:id=>"1",
   :attributes=>
    {:email=>"",
     :name=>"Burdette Schmeler",
     :school_id=>1}}}
```

So, in my spec file, i need to put in this way:

```
  context 'is student serialize working?' do
    let(:student) { create(:student) }

    it 'serializes' do
      expect(serializer).to include_json(
        data: {
          id: student.id.to_s,
          attributes: {
            name: student.name,
            email: student.email,
            school_id: student.school_id,
          }
        }
      )
```